# Loop only a portion of YouTube video in <iframe>

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to use a YouTube video as a website background with the following restrictions:

 1. play only a portion of the video (say, from 8s to 20s)

 2. loop **only this portion** of the video

 3. remove the loading .gif between video loopings

The issue is that the video loops from the very start after playing from the specified time. I Googled looping a portion of video but i couldn't fix it. Following is my code:

`<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://youtube.com/embed/lknBm2wGm0k?
    autoplay=1
    &controls=0
    &showinfo=0
    &autohide=1
    &start=30
    &end=40
    &playlist=lknBm2wGm0k
    &loop=1
    &rel=0"></iframe>`

Please help me fix 2. and 3. The question may be a possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268305/how-to-loop-only-a-portion-of-a-youtube-video) but I wish to avoid the re-loading between loops as well, i.e. replay the already buffered video.

Answer (score 0):

A flash background is a mess... Btw try to upload your own video or maybe postprocess the video yourself so you can use it without limitations.